# Converting abbreviated "numbers" into numbers in R

Tags: r, type-conversion, analysis, bigdata

I have a data frame in R that has monetary values such as `$25,000` and `$2,000,000` entered as `25K` and `2M` respectively. The data frame is massive, so is there any way I can, for example, change all of the `2M`'s to `2000000`'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try gsub() on the letters:

```
df$variableName <- gsub("M", "000000", df$variableName)
df$variableName <- gsub("K", "000", df$variableName)
```

and so forth...

Maybe convert the class when you're done `class(df$variable) <- "numeric"`.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you very much